# Android cannot change the startup page

Tags: flutter

[image]

After restarting, it still remains my logo with a white background image. Is it necessary to have a fixed size image for the startup page to take effect? Can I ask if there is anything I haven't modified

I would like to replace the startup image with a picture of my own choice

Answer (score 0):

It coudl be happening two things:
-The resolution of the image. Check if you have more resolutions. Sometimes its a problem to render the images due this fact.
-The bitmap configuration. Try with this code:

```
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
        android:config="RGB_565"/>
```

Hope this can help you :)